# Problem to call Hcaptcha callback function

Tags: javascript, 2captcha

I come to see you because I have been blocking for a week to send the hcaptcha response to Google.

To put it in context, I'm developing a web automation program in Python with Selenium at releases.footshop.com website.
The captcha is at the end of the forms and should activate the "Finish your order" button

I manage to retrieve the response to the hcaptcha sent by 2 captcha, then put it in the h-captcha textbox.
But impossible to send it.

According to the hcaptcha documentation, the callback function is called in the POST request.
I have bein found this function, it is hcaptchaOnLoad:
https://hcaptcha.com/1/api.js?render=explicit&onload=hcaptchaOnLoad

I also found the index.js file where the hcaptcha function is defined and where hcaptchaOnLoad is called. https://pastebin.com/8MZb0P0B

```
// Generate hCaptcha API Script
var CaptchaScript = function CaptchaScript(hl, reCaptchaCompat) {
  // Create global onload callback
  window.hcaptchaOnLoad = function () {
    // Iterate over onload listeners, call each listener
    onLoadListeners = onLoadListeners.filter(function (listener) {
      listener();
      return false;
    });
  };
```

I enclose the tests that I was able to do in the Chrome console and Firefox as well as my 2captcha code.

[Chrome tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdFqh.png)

[Firefox tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVfPQ.png)

[Python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KevTy.png)

Regards,
Mart

Answer (score 2):

Try this .may helps
https://2captcha.com/blog/hcaptcha-cloudflare-en
With their addon , i can bypass the hcaptcha
But the callback function name keep changing
So i'm not able to call it in code .

Comment: can you expand on your answer, what methods did you try. How did you get the callback function to work even in 1 instance.

Comment: Hello,

Sorry for the late response, after more than a month of research I put my project aside ...
But I'm still interested in knowing the answer.

You say the name of the function changes every time, can you tell me where you find it?

Thanks in any case for these answers, I have already seen with the 2captcha admin who unfortunately didn't manage to help me